# Apache CAMEL + HTTPS REST API (post)

Tags: https, apache-camel, camel-http

Im a newbie to apache camle and 
Lately Ive been trying to make a post request to a HTTPS Rest API. 
I have gone through many posts and documentation but still I couldnt get a gist of this. 
Please find my code below

**

```
from("timer:aTimer?period=20s")
            .process(ex->ex.getIn().setBody( 
                    "{\n" + 
                    "                       \"userId\": 777,\n" + 
                    "                       \"title\": \"sample\",\n" + 
                    "                       \"body\": \"my body\"\n" + 
                    "                   }"
                    ))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,constant("POST"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,constant("application/json"))
            .to("restlet:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .log("${body}");**
```

Whenever I run my application im getting the below error.

```
Started
INFO  DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
INFO  ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
INFO  DefaultTypeConverter - Type converters loaded (core: 192, classpath: 14)
INFO  DefaultCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
Mar 05, 2018 3:20:45 PM org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper start
INFO: Starting the Apache HTTP client
INFO  DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: timer://aTimer?period=20s
INFO  DefaultCamelContext - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
INFO  DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.879 seconds
INFO  DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 300 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 1]
INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy - There are 1 inflight exchanges:
    InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-ubuntu-Latitude-6430U-1520243444162-0-1, fromRouteId=route1, routeId=route1, nodeId=to1, elapsed=0, duration=3018]
INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 299 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 1]
INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy - There are 1 inflight exchanges:
    InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-ubuntu-Latitude-6430U-1520243444162-0-1, fromRouteId=route1, routeId=route1, nodeId=to1, elapsed=0, duration=4020]
INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 298 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 1]
INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy - There are 1 inflight exchanges:
    InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-ubuntu-Latitude-6430U-1520243444162-0-1, fromRouteId=route1, routeId=route1, nodeId=to1, elapsed=0, duration=5023]
Mar 05, 2018 3:20:51 PM org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall sendRequest
WARNING: An error occurred during the communication with the remote HTTP server.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:339)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:363)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:81)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:119)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:342)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:355)
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.process(RestletProducer.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

WARN  TimerConsumer - Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-ubuntu-Latitude-6430U-1520243444162-0-1]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException - Restlet operation failed invoking https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:80/443:posts with statusCode: 1001 /n responseBody:HTTPS/1.1 - Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server]
org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:80/443:posts with statusCode: 1001 /n responseBody:HTTPS/1.1 - Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.populateRestletProducerException(RestletProducer.java:304)
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer$1.handle(RestletProducer.java:190)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter$1.handle(ClientAdapter.java:90)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:371)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:81)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:119)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:342)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:355)
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.process(RestletProducer.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
ERROR DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-ubuntu-Latitude-6430U-1520243444162-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-ubuntu-Latitude-6430U-1520243444162-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:80/443:posts with statusCode: 1001 /n responseBody:HTTPS/1.1 - Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [timer://aTimer?period=20s                                                     ] [      5321]
[route1            ] [process1          ] [Processor@0x33ae3bf8                                                          ] [         4]
[route1            ] [setHeader1        ] [setHeader[CamelHttpMethod]                                                    ] [         0]
[route1            ] [setHeader2        ] [setHeader[Content-Type]                                                       ] [         0]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [restlet:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/443:posts                        ] [      5308]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:80/443:posts with statusCode: 1001 /n responseBody:HTTPS/1.1 - Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.populateRestletProducerException(RestletProducer.java:304)
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer$1.handle(RestletProducer.java:190)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter$1.handle(ClientAdapter.java:90)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:371)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:81)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:119)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:342)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:355)
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.process(RestletProducer.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Mar 05, 2018 3:20:52 PM org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper stop
INFO: Stopping the HTTP client
INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy - Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: timer://aTimer?period=20s
INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 3 seconds
INFO  DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 7.927 seconds
INFO  DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 3.048 seconds
```

Please help me.. I've also tried to use Apache HTTP4 component but still no luck.

Comment: If you must use HTTPS (eg secured) then you need to setup all that security stuff - try look at the unit tests of camel-restlet

Comment: Thanks a bunch. But could you please give me examples or links?

Comment: Have you managed to fix this one ?

Comment: Used Apache HTTP4 component to resolve this.